# Android present streamed images

Tags: android, streaming

I want to present bitmap images from a internetstream. Every 500 millisec i get a new image and i want to present this image to the user. What is the best way to do this? Can i use an image view and chenge the image every 500 millisec?

I tried to do this in an timer task like this:

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if(flag){
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                Log.i(APPID, "New frame");
                try {
                    bmp = session.getImage();
                    setImage(bmp);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 500, 500);
```

But this does not work.

Comment: do you get any exceptions. looks like  your updating ui on the background thread

Comment: this warnings: WARN/System.err(2202): at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:401)
WARN/System.err(2202): at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:416)

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: Well this is all i get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the UI from a thread other than the UI/main thread will fail as Android does not allow it. Try using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post messages back to the UI thread. You could do something like this.

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if(flag){
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    Log.i(APPID, "New frame");
                    try {
                       bmp = session.getImage();
                       setImage(bmp);   
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}, 500, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Timer task runs on a different thread. you need to update ui on the ui thread. You should use `runOnUiThread` or `Handler`

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui threa
 {
         public void run() 
         { 
                // update ui here   
         }
  });
```

Handler

```
   Handler m_handler;
   Runnable m_handlerTask ; 

   m_handler= new Handler();  
   m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
           {
               @Override 
               public void run() { 
                    // do soemthing 

                    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    
                            // change 1000 to whatever you want 

               }
          };
          m_handlerTask.run();
```

When you wan to cancel call this `m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`.

Comment: Yes i implemented like you said with the runOnUiThread method. Thanks!